# How do I \write18 a koma var?

Tags: errors, koma-script, shell-escape, write

I'm trying to do some shell processing of data that depends on the settings inside the TeX file.
To do this I want to `\immediate\write18` a command that depends on a `\usekomavar`, but `pdflatex` complains about an extra `}`.

MRE:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\newcommand\x[1]{hello #1} 

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Person} % <- toname should be 'Person'
\opening{Opening}

\immediate\write18{echo 'none' > \jobname-none.txt} % fine
\immediate\write18{echo '\x{world}' > \jobname-x.txt} % fine
\immediate\write18{echo '\usekomavar{toname}' > \jobname-toname.txt} % error

\closing{Closing}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Specifically it tells me:

```
$ pdflatex --shell-escape mre.tex
...snip...
! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.12 ...usekomavar{toname}' > \jobname-toname.txt}
```

Importantly, I do not want to escape the command. The file contents should be `Person`, not `\usekomavar{toname}` after the command was run.

Comment: \usekomavar is not expandable.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm not sure I understand what that means or what to do with that information. Can you elaborate?

Comment: it means it will not work. it won't expand to a simple data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

KoMa variables are basically macros saved under the name `\scr@VARNAME@var`. `\usekomavar` is a robust macro that checks whether the variable is defined and whether a star follows, in which case it does something else. If you are ready to give up these checks you can just use `\csname scr@VARNAME@var\endcsname`. Worst case: the KoMa var is undefined and nothing happens.

```
\immediate\write18{echo '\csname scr@toname@var\endcsname' > \jobname-toname.txt}
```

Answer (score 7):

As Ulrike said, `\usekomavar` is not expandable, but a functionally-equivalent expandable version can be easily created.  Being non-expandable means that the command does assignments as part of its processing, so it fails when used inside an `\edef` or a `\write`.  The command below uses only expandable commands, so that inside the `\write` it expands to the value of the variable.

```latex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\newcommand\x[1]{hello #1}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\xusekomavar{sO{\use:n}m}
  {
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
      { \__bitmask_usekomathing:nnn {name} }
      { \__bitmask_usekomathing:nnn {var} }
          {#2} {#3}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__bitmask_usekomathing:nnn #1 #2 #3
  {
    \cs_if_exist:cTF { scr@#3@var }
      { \exp_args:Nnc \use:n {#2} { scr@#3@#1 } }
      { \msg_expandable_error:nnn { bitmask } { undefined-komavar } {#3} }
  }
\msg_new:nnn { bitmask } { undefined-komavar }
  { KOMA-Script~variable~`#1'~not~defined. }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Person} % <- toname should be 'Person'
\opening{Opening}

\immediate\write18{echo 'none' > \jobname-none.txt} % fine
\immediate\write18{echo '\x{world}' > \jobname-x.txt} % fine
\immediate\write18{echo '\xusekomavar{toname}' > \jobname-toname.txt} % error

\closing{Closing}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: 1. I was too slow. 2. In both cases, with and without the star, the variable which is checked is `scr@#3@var` even if `scr@#3@name` is returned, so your code isn't 100% functionally equivalent.

Comment: @Skillmon Er... My version fixes a bug?  It doesn't make much sense to check for `@var` and use `@name`, I think.  But you're right

Comment: Well it does, since the `@name` can be defined for every variable type, but the `@var` is only defined if the user set the variable. Whether it's a bug or not I don't know, but it could make sense to check for `@var` either way.

Comment: @Skillmon Changed it

Comment: Well, it checks for the existence of the _variable_ but either returns the _value_ or the _name_. When used as documented a `...@name` should never exist without a `...@var`.This is why `\Ifkomavar` also only checks `...@var`. The name really is some meta value: `\setkomavar{fromname}[Sender]{Clemens}` where the variable `fromname` has the label `Sender` and the value `Clemens` The manual calls the _description_ and _content_.

Comment: @cgnieder Oh, that makes sense.  Reading the documentation pays off, it seems :)  Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 7):

It is also possible to use the optional argument of `\usekomavar`. Therefore I have to define a new macro which will take the content for the file as its last argument.

```latex
\newcommand\writetofile[2]{% \writetofile{<file>}{<content>}
  \immediate\write18{echo '#2' > #1}%
}
```

Then it is possible to use

```latex
\usekomavar[\writetofile{\jobname-toname.txt}]{toname}
```

to get the desired result.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\newcommand\x[1]{hello #1} 

\newcommand\writetofile[2]{% \writetofile{<file>}{<content>}
  \immediate\write18{echo '#2' > #1}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Person} % <- toname should be 'Person'
\opening{Opening}

\immediate\write18{echo 'none' > \jobname-none.txt}% fine
\immediate\write18{echo '\x{world}' > \jobname-x.txt}% fine
\usekomavar[\writetofile{\jobname-toname.txt}]{toname}%

\closing{Closing}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

or

```latex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\newcommand\x[1]{hello #1} 

\newcommand\writetofile[2]{% writetofile{<file>}{<content>}
  \immediate\write18{echo '#2' > #1}%
}

\newcommand\writekomavar[2]{% \writekomavar{<file>}{<variable>}
  \usekomavar[\writetofile{#1}]{#2}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Person} % <- toname should be 'Person'
\opening{Opening}

\immediate\write18{echo 'none' > \jobname-none.txt}% fine
\immediate\write18{echo '\x{world}' > \jobname-x.txt}% fine
\writekomavar{\jobname-toname.txt}{toname}%

\closing{Closing}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```